# What is the unix command to see how much disk space there is and how much is remaining?

Tags: unix, aix, diskspace

I'm looking for the equivalent of right clicking on the drive in windows and seeing the disk space used and remaining info.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look for the commands `du` (disk usage) and `df` (disk free)

Answer (score 19):

Use the df command:

df -h

Answer (score 7):

```
df -g .
```

Option g for Size in GBs Block and . for current working directory.

Answer (score 6):

I love doing `du -sh * | sort -nr | less` to sort by the largest files first

Comment: You might want to make that 'du -s *...' instead.  'sort -n' thinks that 1015K is larger than 65M.

Comment: true... my bad...  also.. one must be careful depending on the system... BSD support sort -nr ... it's different in linux...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see how much space each folder ocuppes:

du -sh *

- `s` – summarize
- `h` – human readable
- `*` – list of folders

Answer (score 4):

Note: The original question was answered already, but I would just like to expand on it with some extras that are relevant to the topic.

Your AIX installation would first be put into volume groups. This is done upon installation.

It will first create rootvg (as in root volume group). This is kinda like your actual hard drive mapped.

This would be equivalent to Disc Management in Windows. AIX wont use up all of that space for its file systems like we tend to do it in consumer Windows machines. Instead there will be a good bit of unallocated space.

To check how much space your rootvg would have you use the following command.

```
lsvg rootvg
```

That would stand for list volume group rootvg. This will give you information like the size of physical partitions (PP), Total PPs assigned to the volume group, Free PPs in the volume group, etc. Regardless, the output should be fairly comprehensive.

Next thing you may be interested in, is the file systems on the volume group. Each file system would have certain amount of space given within the volume group it belongs to.

To check what file systems you got on your volume group you use the following command.

```
lsvgfs rootvg
```

As in list volume group file systems for rootvg.

You can check how much space each file system has using the following command.

```
df
```

I personally like to refine it with flags like -m and -g (in megabytes and gigabytes respectively)

If you have free space available in your volume group, you can assign it to your file systems using the following command.

```
chfs -a size=+1G /home
```

As in change file system attribute size by adding 1 G where file system is /home. use man chfs for more instructions. This is a powerful tool. This example is for adjusting size, however you can do more with this command than that.

Sources:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-rootvg/
+ My own experience working with AIX.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are superficially correct. However, the proper answer is

```
 apropos disk   # And pray your admin maintains the whatis database
```

because asking questions the answers of which lay at your fingertips in the manual wastes everybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

`su -sm ./*`

You can see every file and folder size (-sm=Mb ; -sk=Kb) in the current directory like a list. This way runs in all Unix/Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

du -sm *    => RULLLLLEZ

Answer (score 0):

```
df -tk
```

for Disk Free size in 1024 byte blocks